# how to separate sentence in excel to one column?

Tags: excel

I am looking for a way to separate text to one column (column A) so each word will be separate.

I have searched filmier questions in stack overflow and all the questions are about how to spread the words width.

This is how it should look like in the end.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy27U.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, well an esay way would be using the stock text to columns function that excel has.  Select the cell that has the sentence and then under the data tab click text to columns, select delimited and then use space as the delimiter.  It is a bit more basic than using some code.

Comment: If needed, a subsequent Copy, Paste Special, Values + Transpose would reorient the split words into a vertical array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that goes into a module code sheet.

[image: split_words_code]

This is how it looks in the end.

[image: split_words]

Comment: I need to rearange more the 1000 rows to be set in one vertical coulmn,